# rc.local is not running /sbin/ifconfig command

Tags: rc

/etc/rc.local code,

```
echo "rc.local has started successfully" > /home/sk/tmp/init.log

isEthConfigured=$(ifconfig eth0 | grep "inet addr")
echo "rc.local has run ifconfig command well, with result - $isEthConfigured" >> /home/sk/tmp/init.log

if [[ -z "${isEthConfigured// }" ]];then
  echo "changing the iptables stuff" >> /home/sk/tmp/init.log
  sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -d 10.199.48.0/24 -j REJECT
fi

echo "rc.local has completed successfully" >> /home/sk/tmp/init.log
exit 0*
```

I am adding iptables rules, if i am not using eth0 interface. However, rc.local is not running the code inside if block.

In my init.log, i see only a single line message as,

```
rc.local has started successfully
```

So, does rc.local access the binaries inside /sbin folder?

Why  `rc.local` is not running the second half of the script..

Comment: What shell is rc.local running with? /bin/sh is not necessarily bash.

Comment: yup, it runs with /bin/sh.. afaik, /bin/sh runs ifconfig

Comment: Post the whole script. A shell script starts with a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) line. And watch for this script's output on the console, or add a redirection to a log file. Add `set -x; exec >/root/rc.local.log 2>&1` to get everything logged in `/root/rc.local.log` and post that file.

Answer (score 1):

The shell is run with the shebang, `#!/bin/sh -e`. `-e` indicates, that the shell must exit on the first command that returns non-zero status/error.

In  my code above, `grep "inet addr"` returns error, 1 when it could not find any matches. This causes the rc.local to come out.

To suppress `grep` returning error, i changed the command as,

```
isEthConfigured=$(ifconfig eth0 | grep "inet addr"  || :)
```

Really tricky to find, but thanks to Gilles and the other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952177/whats-the-meaning-of-the-parameter-e-for-bash-shell-command-line).